Heising Modulation Reactor Inductance
I am trying to build a simple 5W tube Radio AM transmitter using Heising modulation. There is one thing I don't understand though. Does the inductance of the Heising reactor matter as long as it's over a certain minimum value (to get good modulation)? It would seem logical to me that a higher inductance would lead to better modulation, but I'm still learning so I would love to hear your suggestions. For example, I've seen in most schematics an inductance of like 5-15H, is 30H too much?

Reference: https://www.w8ji.com/Heising%20modulation.htm
If you're referring to L1, it's simply to behave as an RFC to audio frequencies.  The value needs to be large enough such that, at the given load impedance (some kohms for a 6L6, but a 5W amp might be 10k or so), the reactance is higher than the load resistance at the minimum frequency of interest.  (The condition RL = XL gives the -3dB cutoff.)
An AM phone application only needs 500-3000Hz bandwidth, so not very much inductance is necessary.  Or if you're targeting something more like commercial broadcast, under 100 or 50Hz might be desirable.

So if I understand correctly, the inductance could be too large such that the audio output drops because of the too high impedance at those frequencies?

No, inductor and load are in parallel.
